# Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: react-native

I get an error when I run the ios simulator. As soon as I login, the app crashes.

I was on the branch master, everything was working fine. I created a new branch 'android' and ran the android simulator, fixing a few things related to android. Then I wanted to make sure things still looked good in iPhone, so I ran to iPhone simulator and that's when I got the bug. The screen does not crash immediately. It crashes as soon as I login. The android simulator runs perfectly fine though. I figured I would 'git checkout master' branch to pinpoint what exactly caused that error, but the error persisted on the master branch. That doesn't make much sense to me.

This is my stacktrace:

```
Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[74,24],[19,1],[[64,2000,1552169087432,false]],415]

RCTFatal
-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]
__34-[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]_block_invoke
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_1::operator()() const
void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper::__call<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_1&>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_1&&&)
std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_1, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_1>, void ()>::operator()()
std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>)
CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK
__CFRunLoopDoBlocks
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
+[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop]
NSThread__start
_pthread_body
_pthread_body
thread_start
```

I have no idea how to debug this issue. It came out of nowhere and reverting to previous commits isn't helping. The error details don't give me much to work with. Please help!

Here are my package.json dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
"antd-mobile-rn": "^2.2.1",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
"bugsnag-react-native": "^2.14.0",
"bugsnag-sourcemaps": "^1.1.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"node": "^10.15.1",
"npm": "^6.7.0",
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-native": "^0.58.4",
"react-native-alert-async": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
"react-native-cached-image": "^1.4.3",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.7.1",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
"react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
"react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
"react-native-step-indicator": "0.0.9",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
"socks": "^2.3.0",
"tinycolor2": "^1.4.1"
```

Let me know what additional information I can provide.

Comment: Did you try closing the packager before you ran it on ios?

Comment: Yes I had tried that but no luck! I fixed it now, I had to go to a few previous commits before a 'react-native upgrade' and it worked again.

Comment: Can you please let us know what exactly you fixed react native code?

Comment: Personally, after a nightmare debugging, I was wrongfully attempting to show an object in an Alert function, maybe look into that kind of mistake

Comment: In my case, I was not updating an array state correctly, checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js

Answer (score 84):

This a very generic (and complex) error and there could be a number of reasons behind it, so I'll post 2 ways of trouble shooting this one, an easy one that "may" work, and a harder one that will "definitely" work.

## Easy method (may not work):

**Eliminating the low hanging fruit first (NaN, Infinity issues):**

- **Step 1:** Copy the full error message, paste it on a text editor, maybe even beautify it with something like https://beautifier.io/
- **Step 2:** Search for the string **NaN**, or the string **Infinit**.

If you're lucky you'll notice that you're probably accidentally passing a **NaN** value as a component style, or a component prop. Fixing that value will fix the issue.

**How you'll figure out which component or style that is:**

You'll have to check the information/props/values **around** the NaN value. (i.e you pass a generic prop/value pair that takes a custom string, like `fontName: 'fooBar'` on that same style, that should give away the position/filename of the issue, since you now know where you added that custom fontName.)

## The complex one (will work):

**Why that error is thrown - along with some context:**

(if you don't care about the context you can jump directly to the "How to troubleshoot" section)

As you probably know, react-native used to use the react-native bridge to pass information over to the native side. To do that it uses a very weird format of arrays, so let's look at the error above:

```js
[
    [74, 24],
    [19, 1],
    [
        [64, 2000, 1552169087432, false]
    ], 415
]
```

This is a batched bridge message, which basically means, a series of messages were sent over the bridge (because react-native batches them to save resources).

The **first array** contains the **module ids** that were called

The **second array** contains the **module method ids** that were called

The **third array** contains the **params** those methods were given.

> In the example above the **module 74** called the **method 19** and was given params **[64, 2000, 1552169087432, false]**

The problem can be identified easily here since the second call **module 24**, which called **method 1** was expecting params but nothing was passed as params to it.
For the call to be correct the third array should contain another child (like so:

```js
[
    [74, 24],
    [19, 1],
    [
        [64, 2000, 1552169087432, false],
        [] // <-- that was missing
    ], 415
]
```

Thus the `field sizes are different` error.
That's because react-native expects that for every given call, all [3 fields should contain information](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a1b7a20779cf6496a3e76d9562bfcbfe3339e518/packages/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp#L50).

The reason params were missing is because one of our modules didn't like one of our inputs (specifically the parameter type we were passing) and decided to crash silently.
Our app didn't crash but wrong information was sent over the bridge.

That being said, all we must do now is figure out where the problem is:

### **How to troubleshoot (solution):**

To figure out who the troublemaker module is, we'll **go through all of the message method calls** that were sent via the bridge in the above batched message (as indicated in our crash log).

##### What we'll be doing:

> Using the above issue as an example. To resolve that we need to figure out which module the module with id 74 is (module name), and what the method name the method with id 19 is (method name).

Then we'll repeat the same process for every sequence of calls seen in our crash report.

> i.e module with id 24, method with id 1

The goal here is to figure out which native module and method called caused the crash, and since all RN native module calls pass through the bridge we can achieve that quite easily.

All we need now is a way to convert those id's to actual module names, and method names.
We're in luck, because react-native exposes that information via the [BatchedBridge](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a1b7a20779cf6496a3e76d9562bfcbfe3339e518/packages/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/BatchedBridge.js#L23). When a module is [created](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a1b7a20779cf6496a3e76d9562bfcbfe3339e518/packages/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js#L79) (typically when the app launches) [react-native keeps a reference of the module id's and method id's](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a1b7a20779cf6496a3e76d9562bfcbfe3339e518/packages/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js#L347C6-L348). We'll take advantage of that to get the module/method names we need.

##### Steps:

**Step 1:** Add the following code snippet anywhere in your code:

```js
if (global.__fbBatchedBridge) {
  const origMessageQueue = global.__fbBatchedBridge;
  const modules = origMessageQueue._remoteModuleTable;
  const methods = origMessageQueue._remoteMethodTable;
  global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds = (moduleId, methodId) => {
    console.log(`The problematic line code is in: ${modules[moduleId]}.${methods[moduleId][methodId]}`)
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** All you have to do now is set a breakpoint anywhere in your app, and try the pairs of module/method id's as parameters of the `global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds` function like so:

```
global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds(74, 19);
global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds(24, 1);
```

and that will print the suspects names. From there on you'll be in a much better position to figure out what went wrong.

For example, the first call may print something like: `Timing.createTimer` (which is a typical message react-native sends when we `setTimeout` and may not be related to your crash.

**Step 3:** Investigate each of those calls, and look for wrong/weird parameters, you pass to those native functions.

For me one of the calls output: `RNFBAnalyticsModule.logEvent` which made me investigate how we logged events to firebase (right at the time of the crash) only to find out that we were passing a `moment` as one of it's props. Firebase didn't like that and silently crashed, causing the above error.

I hope that saves hours of headache from someone - I spent hours to discover all of the above.

Comment: `TypeError: global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds is not a function. (In 'global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds(13, 12)', 'global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds' is undefined)`

now there's no function named `findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds`, do you have any  idea is this fnction replaced with any other name or alternative to trace those moduleIds and names. thnaks!
since this is too much old answer i think now method or something might be changed or something.

Comment: Hey there, no this is still valid.

`global.findModuleByModuleAndMethodIds` is something WE define on step 1, (not something react-native offers to us).

Please read the answer a bit closer.

Comment: hey, thanks. now i can trace those module names, now i can diging further.

Comment: hey, thanks. i just got my problemetic method, and fix the issue. you just save my life. i can't accept your answer perhaps the guy who asked the question may fix his issue too.

Comment: Very happy to hear that, it took me a while to figure out such issues, I'm happy this helped someone else!

Comment: Hey, I've just one question, what is that last element in the array, i understood 1st array is of moduleIds, 2nd array is of module's methodIds, 3rd array is the array of params of their respective methodId, and what is the last value? In you your example that is 415.

Comment: @kryptonian it's something called the call id. It's a react-native internal which I doubt would be useful to us. I don't know much about it, but here's how it's being referenced: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp#L19 (also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp#L58-L64)

Comment: @kryptonian This is so useful! This should definitely be a medium article.

Comment: You're right mate @oliver. sudoPlz did really a greate job.

Comment: This was an outstanding answer!

Comment: Heroic explanation! Thank you so much @SudoPlz! You should know this has saved many hours of pain and suffering from the world!

Comment: Pure greatness! I am not a React native dev, I hate JS and everything that has to do with React native, but still, with your answer, I managed to resolve the error in spite of the otherwise completely unless error message one gets! Thanks!

Comment: Great detailed answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I think it happened when you pass `NaN` or something `Infinity` to the native bridge.
In my code, it will be like below:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component 
  constructor() {
    // wrong retrun value from `foo()`, this.myProperty will be `Infinity`
    this.myProperty = foo();
  }

  // Component methods here....


  myFancyFunction() {
    // This code will encounter `Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different`
    // `[xxxx, "<<Infinity>>", xxxxxxxxx, true]`
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      //Do something
    }, this.myProperty); //<-- should never be `Infinity` here
  }
}
```

A lot thanks to this link:
[#23835](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23835#issuecomment-493007479)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an inline style misspelled.

"Heigth" instead of Height"...

so basically react-native wasn't able to found that issue and almost drove me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I think its happened when you passing wrong data type so you should check your code that triggering this error and start inspecting from there (is it right input for this field or not)

Comment: As the question author already pinpoints the trouble to a react.js upgrade, your answer doesn't seem to bring anything new/useful regarding other answers. I'll suggest you to delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In React Native, this problem also occurs if you try to console.log/warn an object which is not stringify-able, such as an `axios` request config.

Comment: This was my issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

for me the same error was happened, as a error searching method, I did comment part of components step by step and finally find the point I made a mistake!  :

```
<Animatable.View   style={{marginTop:**Number(this.SearchTopMargin)**}}
```

the type cast was wrong in  : Number(this.SearchTopMargin)
and I removed the type converting and the problem solved :

```
<Animatable.View   style={{marginTop:this.SearchTopMargin}}
```

I need to solve the problem about converting Animate value to number but it is another issue !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue given from the stacktrace isn't really helpfull at all and points eventually to react-navigation. In my case it occurred that I was setting an invalid with property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking input in `TextInput`

```
onChange={e => {
              setPassword(e)
            }}
```

Make sure you change it to:

```
onChange={e => {
              setPassword(e.nativeEvent.text)
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this error because use alert with object
and which call many times
i remove alert start working fine[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in one of my files, I had passed height as a percentage on the props of a library component I was using. I had to change that to an actual number and it started behaving properly again. So from the immediate code snippet below to the one below it.

```js
import VideoPlayer from "expo-video-player";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

export default function Video() {
    return (
        <VideoPlayer
            style={{ width: '100%', height: 250 }}
            videoProps={{
                source: {
                    uri: 'https://foo.bar'
                },
            }}
        />
    ) 
}
```

```js
import VideoPlayer from "expo-video-player";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";


export default function Video() {
    return (
        <VideoPlayer
            style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 250 }}
            videoProps={{
                source: {
                    uri: 'https://foo.bar',
                },
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are you making network call , checkout your request headers. In my case , my code was working fine in both android device and android emulator, but in ios simulator , app threw error. It was because, in request header I had added the request header "Content-Type" with the value of 'application/json'. However "Content-Type" had to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". When I changed that it worked.